# Using something other than the entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures

We have a C# MVC 3 application, and wanted to explore options other than the Entity Framework for working with stored procedures and data.

We currently have the Entity Framework, but it is a nightmare for other developers to take over; where can I find best practices for this, or other samples to read up on?

Comment: *where can I find best practices for this* - What is *this*?

Comment: True, best practices I guess all depends on where and who the information comes from. . . so I'll take "good" opinions for that matter :)

Comment: Micro-ORMs like [Dapper](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). Also, F# Type Providers like [FSharp.DData.SqlClient](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/index.html) provide unparalleled development experience.

Comment: When you can create nightmares with EF you certainly can create even worse with other tools. First identify the real problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, where do I even begin?! But mostly we need to keep this application, as we're understaffed (aren't we all), have to get the application to a maintainable state, and then salvage what we can before moving on. .. . for the time being we'd like to slowly get away from the EF, as it's causing too much trouble with developers understanding it. . .. hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic, PetaPoco & ServiceStack.OrmLite are some of the ones I've used with varying degrees of success. Have a look at some of the samples on the sites. Some of them allow you to map them to existing databases.

I used them as a one man show at various stages over the last couple of years, so I understand where you are coming from. One thing that always comes in handy is IOC and swinging projects around to that way of thinking really does help turn things around.